# Extract a substring on Mac command line

Tags: macos, command-line

After performing a request using curl and passing the response through `jq` I have this output:

> projects/123456789/locations/europe-west2/featurestores/p013600
> projects/123456789/locations/europe-west2/featurestores/p013601

I want to tokenise those strings and get the last part, i.e. I want to return:

> p013600
> p013601

How can I do that in a one-liner (i.e. via piping)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, piping to `cut` does the job

```bash
echo projects/123456789/locations/europe-west2/featurestores/p013600 | cut -d'/' -f6
```